# pg_dump is not the same version as psql

Tags: postgresql, linux, psql, pg-dump

I updated postgres to version 14 with `sudo apt upgrade`.

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1)
```

But `pg_dump` did not upgrade with everything else:

```
pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-2.pgdg20.04+1)
```

Any idea why that is?

I also purged everything postgres and reinstalled `postgresql-14`:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-14
```

But then:

```
pg_dump --version      
Error: PostgreSQL version 12 is not installed
```

Running Ubuntu 20.04.

Update:

Adding results of running `pg_lsclusters`

```
pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status                Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
14  main    5433 online                postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

Comment: Please add the result of  `pg_lsclusters`.

Comment: It seems you have an older pg_dump somewhere on your `PATH` You can use `which pg_dump` to find out from where that binary is taken

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `which pg_dump` -> `/usr/bin/pg_dump`

Comment: @DanielVérité Added result of `pg_lsclusters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `pg_lsclusters` indicates that Postgres 12 binaries were uninstalled without removing the Postgres 12 instance first. Notice how the `Status` column says **binaries_missing**.
The removal scripts takes special care not to destroy your data when you're uninstalling, which is why an instance and its data can be a bit sticky.

To remove the "zombie" instance, use

```
$ sudo pg_dropcluster 12 main
```

Then only the `14/main` instance will remain in the `pg_lsclusters` list, and pg_dump and other client apps that go through the Debian/Ubuntu [pg_wrapper script](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html) will stop choosing the `12/main` instance first.

You may also want to relocate your `14/main` instance to the `5432` port, as it's the default port for Postgres and if you don't plan to have several instances on the same host, using the default port will make your life easier.

Comment: It worked! I had ended up overriding the symlink but this is a proper solution. Thank you!